# jQuery Autocomplete Custom data and display apart from label,value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jsonp, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to pull some data off a json and display them using jquery autocomplete.

The json array contains ID, Title, Date. On the display, I want to show the Title and Date and on click i want to parse the specific ID for that title.

So currently I have:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
      source: function (d, e) {
          $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: url + mode + encodeURIComponent(d.term) + key,
              dataType: "jsonp",
              success: function (b) {
                  var c = [];
                  $.each(b.results, function (i, a, k) {
                    c.push(a.title + " " + a.date) // Displays Title and Date
                  });
                  e(c)
              }
          })
      },
      select: function (a, b) {
          console.log(b);
            // Appends an array with 2 keys: Value and Label. 
            // Both display the title and date as shown above.
          }
      }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>"+ item.label + "</a>" ) 
                       // Here I want to append a.id as class of this
                       // but the only values are value and label.
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };
```

So how can I append `<li class="' + a.id + '">" + a.title + " " + a.date + "</li>"`

Comment: For custom format of the label, _instead of rewriting the whole request_, you could [format it after autocomplete original request](http://salman-w.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery-ui-autocomplete/using-label-value-pairs.html). More about it [here](http://salman-w.blogspot.ro/2013/12/jquery-ui-autocomplete-examples.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're stripping out the extra properties with your `$.each` loop inside of the AJAX success function (as a sidenote, I'm pretty sure `$.each`'s callback does not take a third parameter). Just append a `label` property to each result item and it should work fine:

```
  source: function (d, e) {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: url + mode + encodeURIComponent(d.term) + key,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function (b) {
              var c = [];
              $.each(b.results, function (i, a) {
                a.label = a.title + " " + a.date;
                c.push(a);
              });
              e(c);
          }
      })
  },
```

The widget will work fine with *extra* properties, you just *must* have at least a `label` or `value` property.

Now in your `_renderItem` function, you can access the `title` and `date` property of each item:

```
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>"+ item.label + "</a>" ) 
        .addClass(a.id) // <---
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Comment: for some reason .addClass wouldnt work but since console.log(item) would display the id, I added it on the append() function. Thank you anyhow

Answer (score 4):

Try this. Place the ID in the value of your ajax call.

```
$( "input" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: url + mode + encodeURIComponent(d.term) + key,,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
              return {
                label: item.title ", " + item.date,
                value: item.id
              }
            }));
          }
        });
      }
    }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<li "+ "class="+"item.value + ">"item.label + "</li>" ) 
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

On the $.ajax success you should pass an object containing label and values rather than only the label string, then you can assign the a.id to the item.value. Like this:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
  source: function (d, e) {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: url + mode + encodeURIComponent(d.term) + key,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function (b) {
              var c = [];
              $.each(b.results, function (i, a, k) {
                c.push({'value':a.id, 'label':a.title + " " + a.date}) // Displays Title and Date
              });
              e(c)
          }
      })
  },
  select: function (a, b) {
      console.log(b);
        // Appends an array with 2 keys: Value and Label. 
        // Both display the title and date as shown above.
      }
  }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li class=\""+item.value+"\"></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>"+ item.label + "</a>" ) 
                .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

You may also pass the original object as the label (`c.push({'value':a.id, 'label':a})`), and leave the formatting for the `_renderItem` (where `item.label` would be the same as `a`)